# OpenWebBeans CDI scanning Jersey and HK2 dependencies and throwing error

Tags: java, jsf, jersey, hk2

I am trying to upgrade my JSF 1.1 project to JSF 2.3.9 and have implemented CDI on tomcat 9 following instructions from [Balus C Install CDI in Tomcat](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20intend%20to%20use,the%20ZIP%20and%20unzip%20it.)

So I have valid dependencies, context.xml, beans.xml and listener added in web.xml as per instructions above.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My gradle dependencies are:

```
 api 'org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.3.9'
 implementation 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:2.0'
 implementation 'org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-jsf:2.0.20'
 implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
```

I also have pre-existing Jersey rest endpoints in my Project. The dependencies for that are:

```
implementation "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:${jerseyVersion}"
implementation "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:${jerseyVersion}"
implementation "org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:${jerseyVersion}"
api "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:${jerseyVersion}"
api "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:${jerseyVersion}"
api "org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.6.1"
```

where my jerseyVersion is 2.36.

The project compiles correctly. But on starting tomcat, I get the following error:

```
July 20, 2022 9:28:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener]

org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Constructor Injection Point, constructor name :  org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.GreedyResolver, Bean Owner : [GreedyResolver, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:null, API Types:[org.glassfish.hk2.api.JustInTimeInjectionResolver,java.lang.Object,org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.GreedyResolver], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:344)
at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.bootstrapApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:137)
at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:103)
at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:99)
```

Am not a CDI JSF expert, but I assume this is CDI trying to scan all the managed beans on load and failing. Everytime I start tomcat, the error changes to the same error getting thrown for some other class from Jersey/HK2 dependencies.

Why is this happening? What is the solution for this? Can someone please guide me to a possible way to handle/resolve/correct this.

I also get below error later in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to call getReference(Bean, Type, CreationalContext) before AfterDeploymentValidation
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
```

But I think that's just my second listener (com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener) failing because the CDI did not complete successfully. And I assume this error will go away once I make CDI to behave correctly. Though please let me know if that is not the case. And would appreciate some guidance for this error as well.

Thanks!

**Update**

After updating bean-discovery-mode to annotated, I am still getting the same error:

```
July 23, 2022 11:52:05 AM 

org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener doStart
SEVERE: An error occurred while starting application context path : [/MyApp]

July 23, 2022 11:52:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener]

org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Constructor Injection Point, constructor name :  org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationServiceImpl, Bean Owner : [DynamicConfigurationServiceImpl, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:null, API Types:[org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService,java.lang.Object,org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationServiceImpl], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:344)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.bootstrapApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:137)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:103)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:99)
    at org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener.doStart(WebBeansConfigurationListener.java:197)
    at org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(WebBeansConfigurationListener.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
```

Comment: I think a much easier approach might be to use Apache TomEE Plus 8.0.12, which is based on Tomcat 9 and has JSF already configured.

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher sorry.. that is not an option for me. I need to make it work with Tomcat 9.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you have bean-discovery-mode="annotated" in your beans.xml?

Comment: @jan.supol that did not work unfortunately. Have updated the question with the result of the suggested fix.

Comment: @Vicky, TomEE 8.0.12 **IS** Tomcat 9. It's an enhanced version of it

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher sorry.. what I meant was TomEE is not an option. I need to make it work with Tomcat.